# How to install CertUtil to Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, powershell, certutil

It seems that my version of Windows 7 (SP1, with PowerShell 4) lacks the `certutil` command. I tried to look for a way to add it manually but failed.
Any ideas on how to do it?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to comments, I was able to locate the `certutil.exe` file in `\System32\` but I can't execute any `certutil` command.

Here's a snapshot I have:

[image: certutil running result]

Comment: Which Win7 edition do you use? Home Premium or Pro/Ultimate? Maybe the Home misses it.

Comment: Actually it's the Ultimate 'distro' of Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium has it: `C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe`

Comment: I checked my Win7 ultimate VM and also has the file: "C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe"

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: run it from a normal cmd.exe and not Powershell

Answer (score 1):

When a program cannot be found when you can see that executable in file managers then it's usually because you're running a 32-bit shell, because 32-bit processes are put under [file system redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and `System32` is actually `SysWOW64`. Some related questions:

- [Why can't I launch telnet.exe from a Windows 8 command prompt?](https://superuser.com/q/463395/241386)
- [query.exe can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47697743/995714)
- [Strange CMD errors only when CMD is opened from my program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32454690/995714)
- [GNU Make on Windows cannot see some executables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45679699/995714)

In that case `%windir%\Sysnative\certutil` will work, although the better way would be running a 64-bit shell instead

However it seems **that's not your situation** because you can see certutil.exe in System32. So there are 2 possibilities:

- Your [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is broken so `certutil.exe` can't be found. `%windir%\System32` must always be in `PATH`. Here's an example on my PC:

  ```
  PS C:\Users> $env:Path -replace ';', "`n"
  C:\WINDOWS\system32
  C:\WINDOWS
  C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
  C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
  C:\Users\user\.dotnet\tools
  ```

  Unlike cmd, PowerShell [looks for the file in `PATH` first](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7.1) for security reasons, like POSIX shells. So even if you're inside `%windir%\System32` it still won't run that exe file and you need to use `.\certutil` instead.
- Your `PATHEXT` environment variable is broken. It's the extensions that the shell will look for when you type a command without extension and [contains `COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL` by default](https://superuser.com/q/1027078/241386). If there's no `.exe` in it then your file couldn't be found. You need to run `certutil.exe` explicitly

Either way, your system might be broken in some way and you need to run [`sfc /scannow`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) to fix the system files and environment

Comment: ty for the `PATHEXT` hint - for decades I've wanted control over that but thought it was hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Under powershell you must prefix the executable name by `.\`.

Try with `.\certutil.exe` or use the old school cmd instead of powershell.

Comment: It works here without using ``.\``