# Availbility of certutil on different Windows versions

Tags: windows, security, certutil

I am a bit confused about `certutil.exe`. I have read the information in the link [Server 2012/Windows 8 certutil documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443(v=ws.11).aspx):

> Certutil.exe is a command-line program that is installed as part of Certificate Services.

So I searched for Certificate Services, I found the link [Certificate Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376539(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Certificate Services, a service running on a Windows server operating system.

But can I use `certutil` on command line in Windows 7, 8, 10 in all editions, not only on **Windows Server**? Could you please help to confirm that `certutil` is available on all Windows versions except old ones like **Windows XP**?

Comment: Are you asking if certutil is available on Windows 7,8, and 10 or are you telling us it is? Also, Windows PE is not an "old version" of Windows. It is the Windows Preinstallation Environment. There is an equivalent version of Windows PE for each version of Windows. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hi, I want to ask certutil is available on Windows 7,8, and 10 or not ?. I read information in technet, it seems certutil only available on Windows Server.

Sorry my mistake, so I edited Windows PE to Windows XP.

Comment: A quick search shows it is available on Windows 8 and newer.

Comment: I don't think so. I can use it on Windows 7.

Comment: Confirmed that it is available on Win10. Why not simply run up a VM and install all those windows version (with the 30 days grace license) and test for the availability of certutil?

Comment: Hi @Darius, Thanks for you confirmation.

It takes too much time for install all Windows versions. I will do it if I do not find the answer of my question.

Comment: There are also different editions, like Home, Professional, Enterprise, etc., which may need to be considered...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `certutil` command line utility is available in:

- Windows 7 Pro
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Windows 10 Pro
- Windows 11 Pro

Others to observed that it's (kind of) available in Win7:

- [Is there a built-in checksum utility on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/245775/391675)
- [How to install CertUtil to Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/999880/391675)

However, it seems to be missing in the home edition(s). Keep in mind that it should be run from the normal command prompt (press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type `cmd`).